# Deleting data and cache of an app after being uninstalled with adb

Tags: adb, uninstallation

I used ADB commands to delete the following from my Pixel:

com.verizon.mips.services
com.android.stk
com.google.android.apps.youtube.music
com.google.android.videos

My mistake is that i forgot to reset their data and cache before running the adb uninstall command. Moreover, I used the command `pm uninstall -k --user 0` blindly from an article and i didn't know that the -k switch keeps the data.

Is there any way to delete the data and cache of the above after being uninstalled?

Comment: I haven't tried this but see if this works: `adb shell pm clear --user 0 PACKAGE_NAME`

Comment: Thanks for your permit reply. Will it delete both data and cache for a package name that doesn't exist anymore? I also forgot to mention that my phone is non-rooted.

Comment: I just tried that command. It doesn't work. Sorry.

Comment: *pm enable --user 0 <pkgname>; pm uninstall --user 0 <pkgname>*

Comment: Will factory reset of the phone enough to remove all adb tweaks I've made?

Comment: yes factory reset will bring back every system app. but not necessary such drastic task. can't you pull apk from /system? or extract from stock ROM?

Comment: I tried posting on forums if someone is kind enough to extract com.android.bips and com.android.printspooler from his or her pixel 4a phone (US model and unlocked) using an app called APK extractor or any similar app and share it with me, but I couldn't find anyone to bother doing it for me. The problem is that I'm not ready for full system reset nowadays because of a WhatsApp number which I can't verify if i format.

Comment: google provides download https://developers.google.com/android/ota

Comment: I am aware of that OTA factory images but again I'm not ready for this at the moment.

Comment: install [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-388)
extract [payload.bin](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/how-to-extract-android-payload-bin-file)
mount [system.img](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader) and
extract apk from (priv-)app