# Effect of removing the -k part in the ADB command

Tags: adb

I uninstalled two services using adb command without the -k switch, in particular I typed:

pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.bips
pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.printspooler

Is there a a proper command to restore them back? I tried: `pm enable --user 0` & all it said "enabled" (as shown in screenshot), but I can't find them anywhere. I know that if I removed the user 0 switch then I'm out of luck but I kept this switch and just took the -k switch off to clean up any residual files with these services. Am I still out of luck?

one more question: Will factory resetting my device using the option found in Settings>System>advanced on my pixel 4a phone is enough to restore everything back to the state before applying ADB commands?

P.S. My device is non-rooted
[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the full command you have executed for uninstalling the services?

Comment: @Robert this seems the continuation of [OP's previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234276)

Comment: @AndrewT. No matter if this is a continuation question, IMHO every question has to contain all relevant information. Therefore I asked the author to include all the relevant information. As he is not to stackexchange I thought some "critics" may be good for learning how to ask good questions.

Comment: @Maged Please do not use comments to add essential information instead edit your question. You can edit your question at any time if you want to add important information. A reader encountering your question should be able to understand it without having read all the comments.

Comment: @Robert Yeah very sorry for all the confusion. I edited the original post and added a screenshot of the exact feedback I got from ADB commands but I'm still confused why I can't find these services if I got "enabled"?!

Comment: @Maged Thanks, but for future posts please don't post screenshots of a terminal just showing text. You can simply copy the text and paste it into your question and format it as code, this way it can be processed by Internet search engines.

Comment: Sure I will. I'm not just not as geeky as you guys so I find it harder to select text from a terminal. Anyway, I just wanted to show everything as it is for your analysis.

Comment: Is my situation mysterious to figure out what is going on? At least, is it possible to have these two services shared with me via that app "APK extractor" or something similar to it from a Pixel 4a device (US version)?

Comment: @Maged try `adb install-existing com.android.bips`. You didn't really uninstall the app from the device (just made it invisible for the user), so it's still there.

Comment: it didn't work as it gave me: inaccessible or not found

Comment: from your screenshot i see you forgot ***'cmd** package'* nevertheless the *'pm enable'* looks successful. you maybe just don't see icons in app drawer even already enabled (btw in windows terminal you can mark text with mouse cursor and copy to clipboard with enter key)